# Error during initialization of TrafficLight node in Veins 4.7.1

Tags: omnet++, veins

How can I use the TrafficLight node in Veins 4.7.1 with a custom app?

I tried to add a trafficlight node the same way we add RSU nodes, i.e.:

```
import org.car2x.veins.nodes.Scenario;
import org.car2x.veins.nodes.TrafficLight;

network EV_Scenario3 extends Scenario
{
    @display("bgb=844,629");
    submodules:
    tl[2]: TrafficLight {
        @display("p=150,140;i=veins/node/trafficlight;is=s");
    }
}
```

and define its app in the omnetpp.ini file i.e. `*.tl[*].applType = "TrafficLightApp"`

This method does not work and I got the following error:

> submodule appl: No module type named 'TrafficLightApp' found that
>   implements module interface
>   org.car2x.veins.base.modules.ITrafficlightApplLayer (Not in the loaded
>   NED files?),  at
>   C:\Veins\veins-5.7.1\src\veins\nodes\TrafficLight.ned: 35 -- in module
>   (omnetpp::cModule) EV_Scenario3.tl[0] (id-7), during network setup

Any Idea how to use this node, and How can I generate it dynamically like the car nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMNeT++ does not know a module called `TrafficLightApp` or this module does not implement the `ITrafficlightApplLayer` interface.

If you have created the module `TrafficLightApp` already, make sure that it also implements the aforementioned interface.
If you have not created this module already, you need to create (and [register](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:defining-simple-modules)) it first.

Please note that Veins 4.7 introduces traffic lights but does not provide an application layer for them. You have to build one yourself, implementing the `ITrafficlightApplLayer` interface.